# Adding a job as API

Tags: api

As far as I can understand, the way to add a job is to set it up in your extension as an API.

So I have created the default code using

```
 civix generate:api --schedule=Daily Contact myendpoint
```

Enabled the extention and it appears in the API Explorer

But when I run it

```
cv api Contact.myendpoint debug=1
```

it fails

`{
    "error_code": "not-found",
    "entity": "Contact",
    "action": "myendpoint",
    "trace": "#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(166): Civi\\API\\Kernel->resolve(Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(100): Civi\\API\\Kernel->runRequest(Array)\n#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\\API\\Kernel->runSafe('Contact', 'myendpoint', Array, NULL)\n#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php(311): civicrm_api('Contact', 'myendpoint', Array)\n#4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php(548): CRM_Utils_REST::process(Array, Array)\n#5 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(275): CRM_Utils_REST::ajax()\n#6 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array)\n#7 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array)\n#8 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1246): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)\n#9 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke('')\n#10 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)\n#11 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n#12 /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php(224): do_action('toplevel_page_C...')\n#13 {main}",
    "is_error": 1,
    "error_message": "API (Contact, myendpoint) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)"
}`

So it looks like I'm missing a step somewhere - but can't find it in the docs .. any help?

Comment: Can you check if api(api/v3Contact/Myendpoint.php) file has been  created in your extension folder?

Answer (score 1):

OK I found out what I did wrong

the help message gives

```
Usage:                                                                                                                                                       
  generate:api [options] [--] \EntityName>> \ActionName>>                                                                                                    

Arguments:                                                                                                                                                   
<EntityName>               The entity against which the action runs (eg 
"Contact", "MyEntity")                                                             
...
```

Being new to this I followed the instructions and typed

```
civix generate:api    \Contact \myendpoint
```

Which works without complaint, and puts the end point in the explore  ... but doesn't work.

interestingly

```
civix generate:api    Contact \myendpoint
```

does work - it is the backslash before Contact that breaks things.

Comment: Great. I am used to the command civix generate:api --schedule Daily Entity Action
Without any slashes.

Answer (score 0):

@Alan

you are right - to setup a schedule job you need to create an API and then you need to add that API in your JOBS folder -

But you are trying both together - this is the correct syntax

```
civix generate:api NewEntity NewAction
```

First create your extension folder - then cd extensionfolder

Then run the above code to generate an API

Then you need to create an entry in civicrm_job table - this can be done through SQL or in the front end

Refer: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-api

I guess this helps !!!!

Thanks

Comment: I started from scratch - I was trying to build the API in a existing extension with reports and queries in it.   For some reason ( that I can't get to the bottom of ) is in the reports extension it didn't work ( generated some different files ), but starting as a brand new extension was fine ..

Comment: I guess your old extension wasn't build using Civix then - try to move the API folder from your newly created extension it should work

Comment: With civix you can create an api and in one go a scheduled job with it. So no need to do SQL etc...

Comment: @Ramesh You used a really old link - I've updated it with the current one.  Doc links now should be to docs.civicrm.org